# Devise reconfirmable not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise email confirmations for new accounts are sending just fine, but reconfirmation is not working for me.
I have:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.reconfirmable = true
```

When I log in (confirmed or unconfirmed) and go to settings to change my email address, it saves the changes, but does not send the reconfirmation email.

I am using mongoid. I added the field :unconfirmed_email to the user model (together with all the others needed for confirmation. As I said confirmation works.).
My user update action is very simple:

```
# registrations_controller
def update
  current_user.update_attributes(user_update_params)
  redirect_to current_user
end
```

My params include the :email field.

When I update the email, it is not copied to the unconfirmed_email field. That field remains nil for some reason.

Any ideas what I may be missing?
I'm using all the most recent versions of Rails, Devise, Mongoid...

### **Update!**

This is driving me nuts.
I went ahead and reverted to Devise's own registration controller:

```
# registrations_controller.rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

and even suspended my own user edit document, so it's now using the basic Devise Edit form.

And STILL, it's sending confirmation just fine when signing up, but does not send reconfirmations.

I have this in devise.rb initializer:

```
config.reconfirmable = true
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days and confirmation_sent_at = Time.now
```

My database fields:

```
# user.rb
field :confirmation_token,                 type: String
field :confirmed_at,                       type: Time
field :confirmation_sent_at,               type: Time
field :unconfirmed_email,                  type: String
```

and I have these Devise settings:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
       :confirmable,
       :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
```

The unconfirmed_email never changes, regardless of how often I update the email.
The email gets updated actually, which is not logical if it was not confirmed.

What am I missing?
How do I debug this?

Comment: aren't you using https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth ? If yes, then here is a relevant issue https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/416.

Answer (score 2):

I have just encountered the same problem.

To debug, I override the test methods of `before_update` and `after_commit` (or `after_update` for mongoid) like this:

```
# User.rb

def reconfirmation_required?
  result = super
  debugger
  result
end

def postpone_email_change?
  result = super
  debugger
  result
end
```

And when the execution is paused by the `debugger` statement, I printed out each term in the boolean expression of [`reconfirmation_required?`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L273) and [`postpone_email_change?`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L262) in console to see if they returned expected values.

In my case, I found that `email_changed` is always false regardless of email changed or not. 30 seconds later I found that `email_changed` is overridden in `User.rb`, and `git blame` shows that another developer did this hack months ago to skip sending confirmation letter when importing accounts.... Removing the hack makes reconfirmable works again.

Hope this piece of information helps. Good luck debugging!

Reference: `Confirmable` source code - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb